# Issue with types conversions

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having trouble dealing with type conversions...

**CODE:**

```
public static string isLocalIncidentSubmitted()
{

    string query = "SELECT Submit From [MVCOmar].[dbo].PrideMVCSubmitLog WHERE ReportID=@existingNum";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr4);

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@existingNum", MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting);

    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    connection.Close();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();


        return dt.Rows[0]["Submit"].ToString();   

}
```

the table submit is of type varchar

I get a large error but here are first few lines of it:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
```

Comment: If you're going to ask a question about type conversions, it would really help if you'd give more details about the types involved...

Comment: the ReportID can only be 36 string letters long. existingNum is also 36 letters long so the problem is somewhere with submit

Comment: secondversionDisplayTesting is of type string, the Submit column is of type varchar with max string length being 5.

Comment: It sounds like ReportID is a GUID, not a string...

Comment: What line causes the error?  What is the type of ReportID.  What is the type of @existingNum?  What is the type of MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting?

Comment: Coding Gorilla has it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `ReportID` is a `Guid` or `uniqueidentifier` in SQL, but you are trying to give it a string value.  Are you sure you're using the correct field in that query?

If  your `MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting` is a string then do it like:

```
Guid g = Guid.Parse(MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@existingNum", g);
```

Comment: the ReportID IS a uniqueidentifier and the value I am passing, existingNum IS a string...if not string what must I pass existingNum as? ReportID is of type uniqueidentifier but I dont know how to convert C# string to unique identifier @Coding Gorilla

Comment: @CodingGorilla I got it working! I put:


            Guid yourGuid = new Guid(MyGlobals1.versionDisplayTesting);
            string query = "SELECT Submit From [MVCOmar].[dbo].PrideMVCSubmitLog WHERE ReportID=@existingNum";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStr4);

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@existingNum", yourGuid);

Comment: I didnt even know of this Guid class before! Learned new things!

Comment: @CodingGorilla [`Guid.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse) is usually a better idea.

Comment: @asawyer It is if you're not 100% sure that your string is actually a a `Guid` in this case I think he's 100% sure it's a `Guid` so `Parse()` is probably more appropriate.  But that's a good point for the OP to consider.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is not with what you are returning, but the SQL you are trying to execute.  Wrap everything but the return statement in a try/catch, and I'm sure you will find confirmation of this.  Your SQL is where your problem lies.

> from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx): The
>   uniqueidentifier type is considered a character type for the purposes
>   of conversion from a character expression, and therefore is subject to
>   the truncation rules for converting to a character type. That is, when
>   character expressions are converted to a character data type of a
>   different size, values that are too long for the new data type are
>   truncated. See the Examples section.
>
> Examples The following example converts a uniqueidentifier value to a
>   char data type.

```
 DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
 SELECT CONVERT(char(255), @myid) AS 'char';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x) instead of .AddWithValue so that you can specify the type and size of your parameter, like so:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@existingNum", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = MyGlobals1.secondversionDisplayTesting;
```